# Organizing code for Testing with Constants from a Configuration File

Tags: python

My application reads in many constants from a configuration file. These constants are then used at various places throughout the program. Here is an example:

```
import ConfigParser

config = ConfigParser.SafeConfigParser()
config.read('my.conf')
DB_HOST = config.get('DatabaseInfo', 'address')
DB_PORT_NUMBER = config.getint('DatabaseInfo', 'port_number')
DB_NUMBER = config.getint('DatabaseInfo', 'db_number')
IN_SERVICE = config.get('ServerInfo', 'in_service')
IN_DATA = config.get('ServerInfo', 'in_data')
```

etc...

I then have functions defined throughout my program that use these constants. Here is an example:

```
def connect_to_db():
    return get_connection(DB_HOST, DB_PORT_NUMBER, DB_NUMBER)
```

Sometimes, when I am testing or using the REPL, however, I don't want to use the values defined in the configuration file.

So I have instead defined the functions to except the constants as parameters:

```
def connect_to_db(db_host, db_port_number, db_number):
    return get_connection(db_host, db_port_number, db_number)
```

And then when my program is run, the constants all passed in to my `main` which needs to call other functions which then call the functions and create classes (which all may be in different modules) that need the constants:

```
def main(db_host, db_port_number, db_number, in_service, in_data):
    intermediate_function(
        db_host, db_port_number, db_number, other, parameters, here
    )
    other_intermediate_function(in_service, in_data, more, params, here)
    # etc...

def intermediate_function(db_host, db_port_number, db_number):
    # Other processing...
    c = connect_to_db(db_host, db_port_number, db_number)
    # Continued...

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main(DB_HOST, DB_PORT_NUMBER, DB_NUMBER, IN_SERVICE, IN_DATA)
```

The problem is that with too many constants, this quickly becomes unwieldy. And if I need to add another constant, I have several places to modify to ensure that my code doesn't break. This is a maintenance nightmare.

What is the proper Pythonic way of dealing with many different configuration constants, so that the code is still easy to modify and easy to test?

Comment: Dear @user1436026, if you think my solution was a real help, don't hesitate to [accept the answer!](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My idea, is really simple, **use optional keyword arguments**.
Here is a little example, what I'm talking about:

```
# collect, the constants to a dictionary,
# with the proper key names
d = dict(a=1, b=2, c=3)

# create functions, where you want to use the constants
# and use the same key-names as in dictionary, and also
# add '**kwargs' at the end of the attribute list
def func1(a, b, d=4, **kwargs):
    print a, b, d

def func2(c, f=5, **kwargs):
    print c, f

# now any time, you use the original dictionary
# as an argument for one of these functions, this
# will let the function select only those keywords
# that are used later
func1(**d)
# 1 2 4
func2(**d)
# 3 5
```

This idea allow you to modify the list of constants only at one place at the time, in you original dictionary.
So this is ported back to your idea:

This is your `configuration.py`:

```
# Your parsing, reading and storing functions goes here..

# Now create your dictionary
constants = dict(
    host  = DB_HOST,
    pnum  = DB_PORT_NUMBER,
    num   = DB_NUMBER,
    serv  = IN_SERVICE,
    data  = IN_DATA
)
```

Here is your `other_file.py`:

```
import configuration as cf

def main(host, pnum, num, serv, data, **kwargs):
    intermediate_function(
        host, pnum, num, 'other', 'params', 'here'
    )

def intermediate_function(host, pnum, num, *args):
    pass

# Now, you can call this function, with your
# dictionary as keyword arguments
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main(**cf.constants)
```

**Although this is working, I do not recommend this solution!**
Your code is going to be harder to maintain, since every time you call one of those functions, where you pass your dictionary of constants, you will only see "one" argument: the dictionary itself, which is not so verbose. So I belive, you should think about a greater architecture of your code, where you use more **deterministic functions** (returning "real" values), and use them chained to each other, so you don't have to pass all those constants all the time. But this is my opinion:)

***EDIT:***

If my solution, mentioned above is suits you, I also have a better idea on how to store and parse your configuration file, and turn it automatically into a dictionary. Use JSON instead of simple `.cfg` file:

This will be your `conf.json`:

```
{
    "host"  : "DB_HOST",
    "pnum"  : "DB_PORT_NUMBER",
    "num"   : "DB_NUMBER",
    "serv"  : "IN_SERVICE",
    "data"  : "IN_DATA"
}
```

And your `configuration.py` will look like this:

```
import json

with open('conf.json') as conf:
    # JSON parser will convert it to dictionary
    constants = json.load(conf)
```

Comment: Now that I think of it, do you know of an open source project that would have many parameters from a config file, but does use more deterministic functions, instead of passing constants around? Still just trying to improve the quality of my code. Thanks.

Comment: First of all I think you have to decide what exactly is your goal. Having a configuration file could be nice, if you need fix but adjustable inputs from the users. Another tip is, to use classes (build your code as a more OO program) they can store and return values anytime you want, without calling methods again and again. If you want to learn look at the sublime text editor's packages, where most of the time they have a configuration file (json) also.